# How can I programmatically access the AWS credentials used by the AWS SDK?

Tags: c#, aws-sdk-net

I want to programmatically access the same 'default' access/secret key used by the AWS SDK for .NET, as described under [Using Credentials in an Application](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html).

For example, looking in App/Web.config, followed by a `default` profile, followed by environment variables, and finally the EC2 metadata service.

Is there any way to accomplish this using the AWS SDK for .NET?